# Basic configuration of OpenSC

Tags: freebsd, smartcard, opensc

I received a *Cherry ST-2000* and a *Reiner SCT cyberJack RFID* smartcard reader and some smartcards. I wanted to learn a bit about how these things work but I seem to fail a basic step. I tried a few tutorials which are all basicly saying, install a few packets and then it'll work.

I installed `opensc` and some accompanying packages (`pcsc-tools`, `libccid`, `libengine-pkcs11-openssl`, `gpg*`) on my machine but `opensc-tool --list-readers` doesn't see any readers. I tried on an osx (brew), raspbian and freebsd machine with the same result. All three detect the usb devices but opensc does not detect the readers.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

- https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Quick-Start-with-OpenSC
- https://hardy0700.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/einrichten-eines-reiner-sct-unter-linux/
- https://xoid.us/2019/07/22/smartcard-with-opensc-and-openssl.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you install pcscd? It is the system process that accesses the readers.

OpenSC and other middleware uses the PC/SC API to pcscd.

To see if pcsc supports your reader, see:
https://ccid.apdu.fr/#readers

Comment: Yes, I did. I suspect that there is something wrong with the modules on raspbian. I installed a ubuntu and there I can access the reader but do nothing where the pin is needed.

Comment: Additionally, try to run pcscd which -df argument in the foreground to see the debugging output. If your card reader is supported, you should see your ATRs printed.